Clarification on the Concept of i.i.d Datasets in Machine Learning
I am currently delving into the field of machine learning, and I’ve encountered a point of confusion regarding the concept of i.i.d. datasets. I have only studied rigorous measure-theoretic probability, so when I read statistics or machine learning textbooks where things can be imprecise and non-rigorous at times, I get very confused. I understand that the term "i.i.d." (independent and identically distributed) traditionally applies to random variables (which is defined to be Borel measurable functions. But I'm fine with just "good enough" functions).
However, I frequently see references to datasets being described as i.i.d. in machine learning literature. This usage is somewhat puzzling to me since a dataset is just a set of (tuples) of values, so how can this be called i.i.d?
Could someone please clarify what this means in the context of machine learning and statistics?
Thank you.

the assumption is that the data you have are realizations of some random variable.

An instance of a set of data is, formally, a realization of a random variable. In effect, if $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ is the probability space in question, and $X : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is your random variable (measurable map), then the datasets arise from the process of "fixing" some $\omega \in \Omega$ (through physical observation) and directly analyzing $X(\omega).$

Sorry Andrew, I didn't see your comment. As an aside, this formal distinction is often not properly made (even amongst the highest of quality research, and outside of the field of machine learning). Many times, you will see a realization of a random variable called a random variable in the literature.

I won't say anything new but just to be slightly more explicit, if you have for example a training set ${(x_1,y_1),\cdots,(x_n,y_n)}$, calling the dataset i.i.d, means there exist random variables $X_1,\cdots,X_n,Y_1,\cdots,Y_n$ defined on a common probability space $\Omega$ such that $((X_i,Y_i))_{1\le i\le n}$ are i.i.d. and $x_i=X_i(\omega)$, $y_i=Y_i(\omega)$.
